# p-value based on quantile of standard normal distribution for mean inequality hypothesis

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, quantile

Let $z$ be a quantile of standard normal distribution. Find p-value for $z=1.89$ and $H_a : \mu>\mu_0$.

The way I tried solving this was by getting the area right of $x=1.89$, which is $0.02938$ but this isn't the correct answer. Including the left tail gives a p-value twice that, around $0.0588$. However, this seems intuitively wrong, since we're dealing with a "one sided" inequality. Either way, I have trouble figuring out how I should go about solving the problem with so little information and how to factor in the hypothesis.

Comment: I think the p-value is $\approx 3\%$ as you found. What is the correct answer you  are expecting?

Comment: @tommik there are possible answers given and this one isn't among them

Comment: Yes I supposed that...in other words, is it possible to know which are the possible answers they give?

Comment: @tommik a) 0.0588 b) 0.1234 c) 0.0249 d) 0.0669

Comment: there is an obvious error in the exercise. the correct answer is a) but only in the case of Two Sided test that is $H_a : \mu \ne \mu_0$

Comment: @tommik I have a similar problem and there an analogous way of solving seems correct, so I believe an error has actually occurred. Thanks for helping me figure out what was wrong!